# Error Handling in Python with SUDS

Tags: python, web-services, suds

I have been trying to control a camera through a wsdl file using SUDS. I have got the code working but I want to place error handling into the script. I have tried different exceptions but am unable to get the script working. When I enter an invalid coordinate I get an error. The code I am using is below followed by the error I am recieving.

```
#!/home/build/Python-2.6.4/python

import suds
from suds.client import Client

####################################################################
#
#   Python SUDS Script that controls movement of Camera
#
####################################################################
#
#                    Absolute Move Function
#
####################################################################

def absoluteMove():

    # connects to WSDL file and stores location in variable 'client'
    client = Client('http://file.wsdl')

    # Create 'token' object to pass as an argument using the 'factory' namespace
    token = client.factory.create('ns4:ReferenceToken')
    print token

    # Create 'dest' object to pass as an argument and values passed to this object
    dest = client.factory.create('ns4:PTZVector')
    dest.PanTilt._x=400
    dest.PanTilt._y=0
    dest.Zoom._x=1
    print dest

    # Create 'speed' object to pass as an argument and values passed to this object
    speed = client.factory.create('ns4:PTZSpeed')
    speed.PanTilt._x=0
    speed.PanTilt._y=0
    speed.Zoom._x=1
    print speed

    # 'AbsoluteMove' method invoked passing in the new values entered in the above objects

    try:
        result = client.service.AbsoluteMove(token, dest, speed)
    except RuntimeError as detail:
        print 'Handling run-time error:', detail

    print "absoluteMove result ", result

result = absoluteMove()
```

The error is below:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "suds.client"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ptztest.py", line 48, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': result = absoluteMove()    
  File "ptztest.py", line 42, in absoluteMove
    result = client.service.AbsoluteMove(token, dest, speed)
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/suds/client.py", line 537, in __call__
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/suds/client.py", line 597, in invoke
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/suds/client.py", line 632, in send
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/suds/client.py", line 683, in failed
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 235, in get_fault
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Error setting requested pan'
```

I am not sure which exception I should be using here. Does anyone know how to catch this error. The x coordinate with the value 400 is in degree's that is why the error happens.

Thanks

Okay I have found the solution. In SUDS if you enter:

```
faults=False
```

into the client definition, this catches faults and gives the reason why the fault happened. The line should read:

```
client = Client('http://file.wsdl', faults=False)
```

The post that I have marked as the correct answer also is able to catch that a problem has happened.

Thanks all

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to catch that exception you should put

```
try:
    result = client.service.AbsoluteMove(token, dest, speed)
except suds.WebFault as detail:
    ...
```

Comment: I have put faults=False and tried to catch suds.WebFault, but still getting that error "No handlers could be found for logger "suds.client"

Answer (score 15):

If you handled all exceptions and errors in your code and your code is working fine but still you are getting below message with your correct output.

Msg : "No handlers could be found for logger `suds.client` "

Then a simple solution is to add this line

```cpp
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

in `yourclient.py` file just after all import statement.

Comment: and don't forget:
`import logging`

Comment: That removes the client debugging, it doesn't fix the issue.  To get the suds.client logging facility running, you must first do a logging.basicConfig call.  eg: `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch [`suds.WebFault`](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.WebFault-class.html) by the looks of that traceback.   The error itself seems legitimate, IE, your requests are being executed correctly, but perhaps your parameters are wrong in the given context.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you refer to a harmless diagnostic message in your comment.  I could suppress messages from suds calling `logging.error()` by assigning `logging.INFO` to `basicConfig` and `logging.CRITICAL` to `suds.client`.

https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation